# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between design and xaml view while in full xaml view

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for the name of the keyboard shortcut to toggle between the design and xaml views while you're in in the "full xaml view" in Visual Studio 2012.

This is a very similar question to that which was asked here:
[Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between XAML and Designer in VS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499782/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-xaml-and-designer-in-vs-2012)

However, the accepted answer given there had a couple of problem for what I'm looking for.  First off, when I use that shortcut (which is `View.ViewDesigner` according to [Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa.aspx#windowmanagement)) with my focus in the Design view, it takes me to the XAML view.  But it causes the full XAML view to instead switch back to a split plane.  Plus it's one-way.  I haven't figured out any way to toggle back and forth between them.  So I'm really looking for a way to toggle back and forth between these panes while staying in the full design mode.

It would be extremely helpful if you could list the actual keyboard shortcut command (e.g. `View.ViewDesigner`), as I've changed my shortcuts quite a bit so the actual keystroke may not do what it would by default.  But given the command name, I can easily map it.

Comment: Did you try the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230143/blend-3-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-design-and-xaml-views

Comment: AFAIK, that's Blend-specific.  I'm not using blend, just the regular XAML design/code editor.

This seems confirmed by looking at that link I posted above with the default shortcuts.  The only shortcuts for F11 are for debugging and are nothing about the design/code panes.

Answer (score 2):

Tested for Visual Studio 2017:

1. Go to **Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard** and select command **View.ViewDesigner**
2. Focus text box **Press shortcut keys:** and type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
3. Open combo box **Use new shortcut in:** and select **XAML Designer** (later also **XAML Editor** and **Text Editor**)
4. Press button **Assign**

Result:

[image]

Shortcut is working no matter if the Xaml window is split or not.

Comment: Verified in Visual Studio 2019. Pressing Shift + F7 toggles back and forth between XAML and Design views. Exactly what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

- Navigate to **Tools** menu of visual studio
- Click the **Options** menu item
- From left pane choose the **Environment** and
  then **Keyboard**
- From right pane choose the Visual C# 2005 combobox item

Now you can easily switch between xaml and the design view by pressing Shift + F7